# Regex to match any word that does start with two fix letter

Tags: java, regex

I need regex that match any word that does start with two fix letter like **CO**, **CC**, **EX**  and **FR** :

1. COYEAR/NUMBER        eg. : CO2001/123
2. CCYEAR/NUMBER         eg. : CC2001/123
3. EXYEAR/NUMBER         eg. : EX2001/123
4. FRYEAR/NUMBER         eg. : FR2001/123

I have created one format: `^[C,E,F][O,C,X,R][0-9]{4}(/{1})[0-9]{1,8}`

This format `^[C,E,F][O,C,X,R]` says entered value should start with C, E  or F and after that any word from  O,C,X and R is allow.

but I have some rules like

```
1)There must be O or C after C
2)There must be X after E 
3)There must be R after F
```

Other combination does not allow.

Sample Test example:

```
public class TestRegEx {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String value1="CC2007/67";

        String value2="CO2001/123";
        String value3="CC2001/123";
        String value4="EX2001/123";
        String value5="FR2001/123";

        boolean value1isVerify=value5.matches("^[C,E,F][O,C,X,R][0-9]{4}(/{1})[0-9]{1,8}");
        System.out.println("isVerify--->"+value1isVerify);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works for you

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "^(C[OC]|E[X]|F[R])[0-9]{4}(/{1})[0-9]{1,8}$";

    System.out.println("CC2007/67".matches(str));
    System.out.println("CO2001/123".matches(str));
    System.out.println("CC2001/123".matches(str));
    System.out.println("EX2001/123".matches(str));
    System.out.println("VR2001/123".matches(str));

}
```

How I applied your rules:

- There must be O or C after C --> `^C[OC]`
- There must be X after E --> `^E[X]`
- There must be R after F --> `^F[R]`

Since only the first one has more than one option for the follow up character, it could be rewritten like this: `"^(C[OC]|EX|FR)[0-9]{4}(/{1})[0-9]{1,8}$";`

But I decided to leave the group, making thins easier in case you wanted to add other possible combinations. You can use whatever version you feel more comfortable with.

And I didn't touch the rest of your pattern, because I don't know what you're matching exactly. But I believe it could be shortened like this:

```
"^(C[OC]|EX|FR)\\d{4}/\\d{1,8}$"
```

Comment: But VR is not supposed to work according to your rules. Your pattern covers `FR` but not `VR`

Comment: Yeah!!, That is my mistake.

Comment: Do you want VR to be added to the pattern? Just edit your original rules and i'll edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

try

```
str.matches("(CO|CC|EX|FR)\\d{4}/\\d{1,8}")
```

Answer (score 1):

*This format `^[C,E,F][O,C,X,R]` says entered value should start with C, E or F and after that any word from O,C,X and R is allow.*

No it doesn't, it says the string should start with `C`, `E`, `F`, or `,`, and be followed by `O`, `C`, `X`, `R` or `,`. I.e. the string `",,"` would match.

Try

```
"^(CO|CC|EX|FR)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a regex you could use `String.startsWith()`. In this case you would check your string against all the valid starting characters.

Comment: Thanks, but I want regex only. I have just create test example for test Regex only.